# Aptana 3 in javascript: when I type "this." the autohelper always changes it to "thistory." how to fix it?

Tags: aptana

I dont know how to use the normal as it were some weeks ago.
This is not so smart as it takes the "his" from "this" and assumes it as "history" instead of "this"

So annoying! It doesn't even show app in the content assist or auto-helper but when i type the dot appears thistory...

It also happens with typing "f." and I get "falert.".. what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug, shown here: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3017

To fix it more immediately, go to Preferences > Studio > Editors > JavaScript, and erase "(" from the "insert proposal" preference.

Comment: I dont have Studio but: preferences > Aptana > Editors > Javascript but I dont have a trigger instead of that I have in the content assist:
display proposals, contextual info, insert proposal

Comment: their values were ".(" and I deleted the "(" but no effect. I deleted all and it works, thanks

Comment: "and erase "(" from the "insert proposal" preference." ->

Bugreport says to delete '.'